# Preserving decimal data format when writing r tibble data to .txt file

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble, readr

I am trying to write a tidyverse tibble to a text file while maintaining decimal format in the out put file, but all write functions seem to convert decimal data with quite a few significant digits. The data looks like this:

```
> glimpse(data)
Rows: 125,784
Columns: 7
$ Lon      <dbl> -123.25, -123.25
$ Lat      <dbl> 38.25, 38.25
$ Year     <dbl> 2014, 2015
$ W        <dbl> 0.999998, 0.000000
$ X        <dbl> 0.000001, 0.500000
$ Y        <dbl> 0.000001, 0.500000
$ Z        <dbl> 0, 0
```

I tried the following:

```
options(scipen = 999)
options(pillar.sigfig = 6)
options(digits = 6)
num(data, sigfig = 6, notation = "dec")
options(digits = 6)
num(data, digits = 6, notation = "dec")
```

None of the above options seem to work and when I write the data to a .txt file as follows:

```
write_delim(data, file = "data.txt", col_names = T, delim = " ", eol = " \n")
```

I always get the following in my data.txt file:

```
Lon Lat Year W X Y Z 
-123.25 38.25 2014 0.999998 1e-6 1e-6 0 
-123.25 38.25 2015 0 0.5 0.5 0
```

As can be seen above, numbers with greater than 1 significant figures or decimal places have been converted to scientific notation. Is there a way to get the data to print as is so that my data.txt file looks as follows:

```
Lon Lat Year W X Y Z 
-123.25 38.25 2014 0.999998 0.000001 0.000001 0 
-123.25 38.25 2015 0 0.5 0.5 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `dplyr::mutate` the data using `across()` and `round()` like:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(across(is.numeric, round, 7))
```

Comment: @B Williams I tried this and it did not work. Before writing the data out to data.txt, it looks fine and is still in decimal form, but when I write it out to file and then open the file to check, the resulting file, data.txt, has the columns X and Y converted to scientific notation.